# R: Prettify xtable() output for printing a matrix or dataframe

Tags: r

Following a suggestion, this is a [repost from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644617/manipulate-xtable-output). I am trying to print out [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/xtable.csv) table from `R` using `xtable()`. The default output is ugly. Is it possible to embed latex code within xtable() to manipulate what individual columns look like? Specifically, I would like to include the `\phantom{}` switch in some of the rows.

Comment: based on the answer in SO version, I've voted for too localized.